# How to set ownership and permissions of files mounted via a docker volume

Tags: docker

How to set ownership and permissions of a file mounted via a `docker volume`
We want to set the ownership of files mounted by a volume to a user within the container using `chown` command and similarly set permissions using `chmod` command. How to do this

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/foo.pem:/opt/conf/foo.pem
  - $PWD/bar.pem:/opt/conf/bar.pem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out uid and gui of the container user with `id username` in container. Then `chown uid:gid foo.pem` outside of container.

Comment: I need to do this on the docker-compose script itself, can't run a separate script from outside

Comment: At first you should just once prepare file permissions and ownership, then run docker-compose

Comment: The files will have the exact same permissions and (numeric) ownership inside the container and without, and you cannot change these permissions with pure Docker options.

Comment: The permissions seem to be fine now, but how to set the ownership options dynamically to what the container expects

Comment: Container doesn't expect anything - you run it with user defined or by default. If you don't know the uid of the user in container, you need to look inside: `docker run imagename id`